# lp print different amount of different pages

Tags: cups, lp

I have a PDF, with two pages. I want to print the first page x times and the second page y times. How would I go about this using *lp*? Is there a way to do this in a single command?

I'm using *lp* right now to print, so for an example I use the following command:

```
lp -d PRINTER -n x output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in one command, but how about two?

```
lp -d PRINTER -n x -P 1 output.pdf
lp -d PRINTER -n y -P 2 output.pdf
```

Comment: Also the conclusion I came to, sadly no way to write it in one command.